# SQL Update a column dependent on other two columns

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, updates

I need help finding out how to properly execute an Update query that will update a column depending whether another column has the newest information.

My Table looks like so:

```
Document# | Revison# | Latest? |
----01--------01---------No-----
----01--------02---------No-----
----01--------03---------Yes---- 
----02--------01---------No----- 
----02--------02---------Yes----  
----03--------01---------Yes----
```

All the Fields above are text fields.

The document numbers can be the same as I receive the same document more than once, but every time I receive a document the revision number increases because the document is the same thing but has been revised. I need to make the Latest? column automatically update by running a query that will check to see if that row is the most recent one.

I have tried making another table and doing a count on the revisions to see if there are any revisions higher than the current row if yes then its not the latest if there is none higher then it is the latest.

I also had an idea of perhaps checking for what one has the latest date and depending on what one has the latest date is the one that's latest.

Comment: How about a trigger that will flip the Latest? column to 'Yes' when Revision# is updated? Or alternatively in your update statement update the Lastest? column when the Revision# column is updated.

Comment: Hello,

The revision number does not change, the revision number for that document stays what it is as it describes what revision of that specific document it is.

Much Appreciated,

M Varga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query displays the results you want in Access 2010.

```sql
SELECT
    m.[Document#],
    m.[Revison#],
    IIf(
        m.[Revison#]=DMax(
            "[Revison#]",
            "MyTable",
            "[Document#]='" & m.[Document#] & "'"
            ),
        "Yes",
        "No"
    ) AS [Latest?]
FROM MyTable AS m;
```

My `[Document#]` and `[Revison#]` fields are both numeric fields.  I presumed you want text as the type of `[Latest?]`.

That approach makes `[Latest?]` only a calculated field in the query ... so the field need not exist in the table and you could use the query whenever you need to see `[Latest?]`.

However, if you prefer to keep `[Latest?]` as a field in the table, you can convert that query to an `UPDATE`.  Just beware that when you add or delete rows, the table data will be inconsistent until you execute the `UPDATE` query again.

This `UPDATE` query works with your sample data in Access 2010:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable AS m
Set [Latest?] =
    IIf(
        m.[Revison#]=DMax(
            "[Revison#]",
            "MyTable",
            "[Document#]='" & m.[Document#] & "'"
            ),
        "Yes",
        "No"
    );
```

Comment: Hi,

This looks like a very promissing step to solving the issue, I have ran the query and received the rows for Document# and Rev# properly.
The last row, Latest? gives an error, and in access it states "syntax error in query expression '[Document#]=4748-00-00-00-002_00'." 4748-00-00-00-002_00 is the Document#

Comment: Please update your question to make it clear the datatype of your `[Document#]` field is text, not numeric.  Identify the datatypes of the other fields, too.

Comment: The query has worked! We are storing the Document# as a Text as well as the Rev# as text.The query seems to function with Rev# being a text but not with Document# being a text. Is there any posibble way we could make it function with text? Maybe by using a LIKE instead of a = comparison?

Comment: Since `[Document#]` is text, you will need quotes before and after its value in the `DMax()` expression.

Comment: I appreciate all the thought that you have placed into this solution. Thank you for your assistance, you have made my day.

Comment: Just an after thought, you shouldnt spend any time on this but, This query updates every single row, is there a way to have it only update if a change is required? For example if i receive a [Document#] 01 and [Revision#] 04, it would only update 03 to No and 04 to Yes? And leave Revision# 02 01 as they are?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with the right `WHERE` clause added to your `UPDATE`.  I don't know if it would gain you a significant performance improvement, though.  I didn't test this one, but it should be close: `WHERE [Latest?] Is Null OR [Latest?] <>
IIf(m.[Revison#]=DMax("[Revison#]","MyTable","[Document#]='" & m.[Document#] & "'"),"Yes","No")`